# C++ conversion of String to int one char at time

Tags: c++, typeconverter

Basic program to create a random number over 10000 and then print out the number in a word format.

The problem is that for the `eNum=atoi(Result[i]);` line I get a compiler error saying about the variable `std::string`

```
Error:argument of type "char" is incompatible with parameter of type "const char*"
```

What does that mean? I thought I was taking a single `char` and converting it into an `int`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


enum Numbers {Zero, One, Two, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven, Eight, Nine, Point } eNum;

void main(void)
{
  int iRnd, iTemp;
  string Result;
  iRnd = rand() %  (sizeof(int)-10000) + 10000;
  ostringstream convert;
  convert << iRnd;
  Result = convert.str();

  cout << "\nRandmon number is: " << iRnd << endl << "Converted Number is : " << Result << endl;

  for (int i=0;i<Result.length();i++)
  {
    eNum = atoi(Result[i]);
    cout << eNum; 
    system("pause");
  }
}
```

Comment: For simple character->integer conversions, you can use `c - '0'`, provided `c` is in the range `['0', '9']`.

Comment: Please read the documentation of the `atoi()` function - after doing that, everything will be clear.

Comment: This code even doesnt compile, how do you want us to help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `atoi()` function expects a C string. Either get rid of your entire code and use

```
int num = atoi(someString.c_str());
```

for conversion, or in your code, change

```
eNum = atoi(result[i]);
```

to

```
eNum = result[i] - '0';
```